When should I use the present simple or the present progressive to describe habitual behaviors?
When I read, I don't want to talk.
While I am reading, I don't want to talk.
When should I use the present simple or the present progressive to describe habitual behaviors like the two sentences above? Is there any difference in meaning between the two sentences? If so, could native speakers explain it to me? Thank you.

The progressive/continuous expresses a sense of being "in the moment" whereas  the simple present is more abstract and presents reading (or whatever verb it happens to be) as an activity.
Consider:

When you hammer on your workbench in the basement, you make noise.
When you are hammering on your workbench in the basement, I cannot hear what they are saying on the TV.

It isn't that you couldn't use simple present when you hammer in the second sentence; it's that the progressive/continuous when you are hammering emphasizes  the sense of being in the moment.
If you make a sandwich of two pieces of bread, a slice of cheese, and a slice of tomato and you don't cut the bread but leave the slices whole, you have a bag lunch. But if you cut off the crust and cut the sandwich into four triangles, you can serve it as a canape. It is all about the presentation.  The tenses present things differently.

The difference between present simple and present progressive in the case of behaviors can be very context-dependent.
There are many instances in which the temporal connotations of the two can be very relevant:

When I read, the children play.

The common reading of this sentence is a habitual one: On the many occasions when you read, the children play on these same occasions.

While I am reading, the children play.

Here, on the other hand, you are referring to a specific instance in which the children play while you are engaging in the act of reading.
In the case that you're asking about, the difference between being in a state where you read and  actively reading is very slim, and probably negligible. This is because your sentence has a proposition that refers to a continual state of affairs, namely your desire to not talk. The function of uttering this sentence will be unchanged regardless of if you are referring to not wanting to talk in the past, present and future states in which you read or the current state of you reading. If you want to be maximally precise, maybe stick with "While I am reading, I don't want to talk" if you plan on talking while reading some other time in the future and "When I read" if that's never going to be on the table.
